# Azurepipeline checkout code from Azure repo and build the artifacts

Tags: azure

I'm working with azure pipeline to checkout source code from azure repo and execute setup of inbuilt script to which is provided by webmethod SAG, Using build.yaml i can able to build my application but not able to publish the artifacts.

cat build.yaml

```
trigger:
- devops-build

pool:
  name: CICD

steps:
# Create Target Directory to keep git repo for later use
- bash: |
   mkdir -p /home/user/cicd_source/dev/packages/packages
  displayName: 'create directory'

- bash: |
   echo "webname=${{parameters.projectName}}" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/devpackagename.properties
   echo "BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/devBuildNumber.txt

Above script will create devpackagename.properties and devBuildNumber.txt following path inside my self hosted agent directory work location.
```

pwd
/home/user/agent/CICD/_work/1/a
ls -lrt
devpackagename.properties
devBuildNumber.txt

```
cat  devpackagename.properties
webname=package
```

```
cat devBuildNumber.txt
BuildNumber=20221004.83
```

After ran the successful pipeline i don't see any artefacts published inside my pipeline

[image: Build image]

Answer (score 1):

after your build steps add below task

```
 - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
   inputs:
     targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     artifact: 'drop'
     publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

you would see artifact get published on the pipeline